# Random based on video input, why isn't there some predictability

Tags: hash

I just saw [this article](https://www.ianvisits.co.uk/articles/inside-the-london-office-where-swinging-pendulums-keep-cyber-threats-at-bay-71054/) and many like them before where they use a video of some random movement and a hashing function to make a cryptographic random number generator

but I'm always curious why this is as "unpredictable" as they claim. These random generators, they're supposed to help with random number generation with the assumption you can't predict what the next frame will look like.

But if you know the hashing algorithm they use and have frame 1, you can't predict frame 2 with a 100% accuracy, I admit, but wouldn't it still greatly reduce the search space because you can assume that the pendulums for example follow the laws of physics?

Comment: What matters is not really that prediction (e.g. per the law of physics) "greatly reduce the search space". It's about reducing the search space so much that it's possible to find the _exact_ input of the hash (because for an ideal or even a passable hash, getting anything else won't help). Perhaps considerations based on sensor noise alone allow to quantitatively rule that as extremely improbable, irrespective of what the video depicts. The devil is in the details, like if bright light will cause a still predictable image, and how exactly the hash is used to build the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is definitely some predictability if we take several snapshots back to back of the same image.  However, if we wait a few seconds, there's still probably enough entropy to extract from the image to not make it matter too much.

Say we use a still camera that takes a full HD (1920×1080) image.  That image has 2,073,600 pixels, each of which will probably contain 3 8-bit components (red, green, and blue).  Now, we believe that 256 bits of entropy should be more than sufficient, but perhaps we want to use a 512-bit output to match an appropriate SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2 hash, just to avoid any future attacks.

With 2,073,600 pixels, we need one bit of entropy from every 4050 pixels in order to get 512 bits of entropy.  And, because we're using a cryptographic hash, the entropy doesn't have to be uniform; it may happen that some areas of the image (such as the parts with the lit lava lamps or the moving pendulums) contribute more entropy than others.  However, other parts, including the background, may help if they're exposed to the outdoors, as in the article you linked, so that can be affected by a cloud moving over the building.

Even with the fact that there's *some* predictability between snapshots, it's likely that, with on average one bit of entropy in 24 bits of colour data for 4050 pixels, we can produce enough random bits in a single image to avoid any risk of correlation between images.  This does, of course, require a good quality camera that can produce raw sensor data that isn't compressed, but if Cloudflare is buying 100 lava lamps (about CAD 4200) for this purpose, I'm pretty sure they can also afford a decent camera.

This is, interestingly enough, the same way that many operating system kernels accumulate entropy.  When an interrupt occurs, a high-precision timestamp is mixed into the randomness pool.  This might have only a small amount of entropy in it (maybe 0.5 or 1 bit), and *most* of the value (especially the high bits) is predictable, but the small amounts of entropy accumulate over time and given enough samples, provide enough entropy.

Even if we are not very confident that one image is sufficient for this purpose, we could incorporate multiple different images from different cameras pointed at the same data, and wait longer (e.g., taking a snapshot every 5 seconds and incorporating 5 images) to give us more confidence that the images incorporate enough entropy and are independent enough from other values.  I don't work at Cloudflare and don't know what their approach is, but I'm sure they employ cryptographers who have thought this situation through quite thoroughly.

Comment: Yes, the time delay is important, however, it is just an advertisement...

Comment: See the [Photonic Instrument & Null Gamma Device](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/) for examples of this in practice. You'll find that the image is not necessary.